Postgresql database does not interaction with my simple Node.js server
Links with server and postgresql database. There are three elements in the register: full name, email, and password, but the information in the register does not seem to be linked to the database. Perhaps the server.js register part is the problem. And I wrote code so that an error message appears in the console window, but the error message does not appear and the site continues to load without being processed. Below is part of the code. Could you tell me what the problem is here? (I am using Node.js, and I am new to coding and have just started.)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    require("dotenv").config()
}


const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt") // Importing bcrypt package
const passport = require("passport")
const initializePassport = require("./passport-config")
const flash = require("express-flash")
const session = require("express-session")
const methodOverride = require("method-override")
const { Client } = require('pg');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');



initializePassport(
    passport,
    email => users.find(user => user.email === email),
    id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
)

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(methodOverride("_method"))

const users = [];

app.post("/login", checkNotAuthenticated, passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true
}))

app.post("/register", checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);

        const newUser = {
            id: Date.now().toString(),
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword
        };
        
        users.push(newUser);

const insertQuery = `INSERT INTO users (id, name, email, password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *`;
const values = [newUser.id, newUser.name, newUser.email, newUser.password];

client.query(insertQuery, values, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Error executing query", err);
        return res.status(500).send("Server error");
    }

    console.log("User inserted:", result.rows[0]);
    res.redirect("/login");
});
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.redirect("/register");
    }
});

// Routes
app.get('/', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs", {name: req.user.name})
})

app.get('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render("login.ejs")
})

 app.get('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
     res.render("register.ejs")
})


// End Routes
app.delete("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout(req.user, err => {
        if (err) return next(err)
            res.redirect("/")
    })
})

function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next()
    }
    res.redirect("/login")
}

function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return res.redirect("/")

    }
    next()
}

'users' table of postgresql
The above code is a code that has been modified few times, and is an attempt to convert the database that previously operated in the console to postgresql. The expected result was that the database information should have been transmitted when signing up, but as described above, nothing happened both console and database.

did you initialize the client with the current parameters? make sure you upload only a specific code portion where the error occurs instead of copying and pasting the full code.
try
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT || 5432
});

pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to database');
    }
});


before registering a new user, try checking if it already exists and sanitize the inputs first.


